# Is it ok to enable proposed updates during Ubuntu's development cycle?

Tags: updates, beta, quality

I like to run the development releases of Ubuntu (alpha, beta, whatever).

Is there any reason why I shouldn't enable **proposed updates** for Ubuntu before Ubuntu is released as stable?

Are proposed updates different after a stable Ubuntu release?

[image: screenshot of proposed updates options screen from software-properties-gtk]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "There is very little benefit to users in using -proposed during the development cycle and such use is strongly discouraged."[1](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ProposedMigration)

After a new stable release of Ubuntu, testers are encouraged to use the **-proposed** repository to test Stable Release Updates to help the Release Team decide whether the update should be released to all users. However, during the development cycle, -proposed works differently and the Ubuntu Developers do *not* recommend enabling -proposed.

During Ubuntu's development cycle, all package updates are first uploaded to the proposed repository. Once the package completes a few basic checks, it is uploaded to the regular repository.

The basic checks include

- Completion of the build on all supported architectures
- Completion of any library transitions (libfoo2 > libfoo3)
- Successful passing of any other automated testing

For many packages, this process can be completed in an hour or two.

If a user has enabled -proposed, they could experience issues with broken packages that have failed some of those basic checks. Generally, it is unnecessary to file a bug about the issue as Ubuntu Developers regularly track which packages fail one of those basic checks.

To summarize, enabling proposed during the development cycle means you have a greater risk of running buggy software and are not really improving the quality of Ubuntu much.

Source:

- [Ubuntu Wiki: ProposedMigration](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ProposedMigration)
- [Original ubuntu-devel mailing list post by Colin Watson](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-October/036043.html)

Answer (score 4):

For development releases `proposed` does not make any sense to turn on.

It is used for automated package testing.

But for stable releases you can enable `proposed` if you want to test unstable packages and report bugs to launchpad. I see no other reason to enable it.

A better way to use `proposed` is not to turn it on permanently, but install selected packages that you want to test at the moment.